# when trying to pass data between 2 controllers, I get the error cannot assign value of type 'ViewController.Item?' to type 'Item?',

Tags: swift, segue

When using a segue, Im trying to pass the information to another controller using

(Taken from ViewController)

```
var itemArray: [Item] = []
```

on the second viewcontroller (InfoViewController) I have

```
var item: Item?
```

This is my segue

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        let InfoController = segue.destination as! InfoViewController
        InfoController.item = sender as? Item
```

Why am I getting the error when both `item` and `itemArray` are in the class `Item`. How do I make it so that they are both the same data type to transfer the data to InfoViewController

Full code for InfoViewController:

```
class InfoViewController: UIViewController {

var item: Item?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

}

public class Item {
    let name: String
    let image: String

```
init(name: String, image: String) {
    self.name = name
    self.image = image

}
```

}

ViewController is too long (150 lines, so I have omitted the search functionality, and the search scope code.

```
  @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet var searchBar: UISearchBar!

var itemArray: [Item] = []
var currentItemArray: [Item] = []


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setUpItems()
    setUpSearchBar()
    self.searchBar.showsScopeBar = true
    searchBar.placeholder = "Search Item by Name"

}

private func setUpItems() {
    itemArray.append(Item(name: "Plastic Bottles", category: .Plastic, image: "1"))
    itemArray.append(Item(name: "Cans", category: .Metal, image: "2"))

    currentItemArray = itemArray

}

private func setUpSearchBar() {
    searchBar.delegate = self

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return currentItemArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as? TableViewCell
    else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

    cell.nameLabel.text = currentItemArray[indexPath.row].name
    cell.imgView.image = UIImage(named:currentItemArray[indexPath.row].image)

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        let InfoController = segue.destination as! InfoViewController
        InfoController.item = sender as? Item
    }

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let item = itemArray[indexPath.row]
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetail", sender: item)
}

public class Item {
let name: String
let image: String
let category: ItemType

init(name: String, category: ItemType, image: String) {
    self.name = name
    self.image = image
    self.category = category
}
```

}

```
enum ItemType: String {
    case Plastic = "Plastic"
    case Metal = "Metal"
    case Paper = "Paper"
```

Comment: Please include complete code for `InfoViewController`, `ViewController` and `Item`. Seems like you have declared `Item` twice.

Comment: it looks you have `Item` type as a member of  `ViewController`. check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you didn't declare the `Item` type as a member of a view controller.

Declare the `Item` struct or class globally in your project.

Comment: That was the problem, it was just one misplaced } that did that! Im new to xcode so im still learning these tiny details. Thank you so much!